# Conjecture: the function $d(x, y):=\frac{\|x-y\|}{\max(\|x\|, \|y\|)}$ is a distance

Tags: metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I make the following conjecture: the function
$$
d(x, y):=\frac{\|x-y\|}{\max(\|x\|, \|y\|)}
$$
is a distance on $H$, where $H$ is a normed vector space or a Hilbert space, and $x, y \in H$ (the function $d$ is defined to be $0$ in the case $x=y=0$). Note that $d$ is scale invariant, i.e., $d(\lambda x, \lambda y)=d(x, y)$ for $0 \neq \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. The property of $d$ which needs to be explicitly proved or disproved is the triangle inequality
$$
d(x, y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y).
$$
The triangle inequality (T.I.) can be easily proved for $H=\mathbb{R}$; moreover, due to scale invariance, it is sufficient to prove it for $\|x\|, \|y\|, \|z\| \leq 1$. The T.I. has been numerically tested by a program which has generated $10^8$ triples of random points uniformly distributed in $[-1, 1]^3$, and the same number in $[-1,1]^6$: all the generated triples satisfied the T.I. This test supports therefore the conjecture for $H=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $H=\mathbb{R}^6$. Since the subspace generated by three linearly independent vectors of a real (complex) Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ ($\mathbb{R}^6$), the numerical test supports the conjecture also for a generic Hilbert space*.

Does somebody know if this conjecture has been already proved, or is able to prove (or disprove) it?

- Before posting this question, I exchanged some e-mail with prof. Egor Makimenko, of the Instituto Politécnico Nacional, México. I did by myself a program for the numerical test of the T.I., but the test cited above has been performed by a program that prof. Maximenko sent me. Moreover, the generalization from $\mathbb{R}^3$-$\mathbb{R}^6$ to a generic Hilbert space is due to prof. Maximenko.

Comment: The term "distance" is also widely used @AWertheim.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @PedroTamaroff. I didn't realize - my apologies if I've offended anyone's sensibilities.

Comment: @BGA I also looked at the $p$ norms on the plane $$||(x,y)||=(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}.$$ I found that considering the points $x,y,z$ as $(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ that the triangle inequality for your distance from this norm with "division by max norm" fails in that $d(x,y)>d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ whenever the value of $p$ is less than $2$. Given your extensive checks, this may mean that $p=2$ is the natural cutoff for $p$-norms to satisfy the associated triangle inequality for the distance you define. IMO that would be interesting.

Comment: I agree @coffeemath, but we have not yet a rigorous proof, and this is strange, due to the "apparent" semplicity of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Let the norm on the plane be the taxicab norm, norm of $(x,y)$ being $|x|+|y|.$ This induces a metric (satisfying triangle inequality etc.) on the metric space $\mathbb{R}^2$, making it a normed linear space.

But with your metric obtained by division of max norms, take the points $x,y,z$ as $(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)$ respectively. Then the usual distances (before division) are $2$ for $x,y$ and each usual distance for both $x,z$ and $y,z$ is $1.$ The norms of $x,y,z$ are respectively $3,3,4$, so that after division by max norms we get
$$d(x,y)=2/3, \ d(x,z)=d(z,y)=1/4.$$
This is against the triangle inequality since $2/3>1/4+1/4.$

So in conclusion it looks to me like the "metric" you propose does not in general satisfy the triangle inequality on an arbitrary normed linear space. I would still like to see if it holds in Euclidean space, since some features of taxicab metric are peculiar.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $p(x,y):= \|x-y\|$ is a metric. Hence we get for free

$$\|x-z\|\leq \|x-y\|+\|y-z\|.$$

Remark: The case where exactly one of the vectors is the zero vector is trivial because we get an inequality of the form:

$$1\leq 1+\varepsilon.$$

If exactly two are zero, we get either:
$$1\leq 1+0,$$
OR
$$0\leq 1+1.$$

If all three are zero:

$$0\leq 0+0.$$

Now consider the case $0<\|x\|\leq \|y\| \leq \|z\|$:

\begin{align}
\max(\|x\|,\|z\|)&=\|z\|, \\
\max(\|x\|,\|y\|)&=\|y\|, \\
\max(\|y\|,\|z\|)&=\|z\|.
\end{align}

So, dividing through the first inequality by $\max(\|x\|,\|z\|)$ we get

$$\frac{\|x-z\|}{\max(\|x\|,\|z\|)}\leq \frac{\|x-y\|}{\max(\|x\|,\|z\|)} + \frac{\|y-z\|}{\max(\|x\|,\|z\|)},$$

but $$d(x,y)\geq \frac{\|x-y\|}{\max(\|x\|,\|z\|)} \text{  and  } d(y,z)=\frac{\|y-z\|}{\max(\|x\|,\|z\|)}.$$

Hence, the triangle inequality is satisfied.

I am optimistic that the other 5 cases can be proven similarly. Don’t hold me to it! I hope you can make some progress from here.

Comment: I already know this. The difficult case is $||x||\leq ||z|| \leq ||y||$.

Comment: Indeed that seems to be the trouble spot.

Comment: We may need some more cleverness to either prove it or come up with a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, I do not think it is a trivial problem

Answer (score 1):

The inequality purposed by BGA fails also in $(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$,
but it seems to be true for the norms induced by inner products.

Hypothesis I: If $X$ is an inner product space and
$\|\cdot\|$ is the norm induced by the inner product,
then for every $x,y,z\in X$
$$\|x-y\|\,\|z\| \le \|x-z\|\,\|y\| + \|z-y\|\,\|x\|.$$

I don't know how to prove this hypothesis in general situation,
but it can be easily proved in $X=\mathbb{R}^1$ and it passes some
[numerical tests](http://esfm.egormaximenko.com/test_one_inequality.html) in $X=\mathbb{R}^3$.

The difficult case ($\|z\|\ge\|x\|\ge\|y\|$) of the discussed triangular inequality $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ follows from Hypothesis I.

Comment: But this inequality does not seem to be easier to prove than the triangle inequality

Comment: Yes, HypI is almost the same that the difficult case of TI. A good surprise it that HypI holds for all $x,y,z$, without any restrictions. Moreover, HypI does not contain $\max$ nor fractions. So, in a certain sense, HypI looks simpler and "smoother" than TI. I hope that HypI is a little step towards a proof of TI.